# Issue with delete functionality ReactJS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeProduct' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I got the products that comes with the props mapped to show in a table, but when I click the button I can't reach the method removeProduct(product) with the onClick method within the button. I'm getting an error like follow:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeProduct' of undefined
    at ProductsDashboard.js:53
    at immutable.js:3018
    at List.__iterate (immutable.js:2208)
    at IndexedIterable.mappedSequence.__iterateUncached (immutable.js:3017)
    at seqIterate (immutable.js:606)
    at IndexedIterable.IndexedSeq.__iterate (immutable.js:322)
    at IndexedIterable.toArray (immutable.js:4260)
    at new List (immutable.js:2067)
    at reify (immutable.js:3572)
    at List.map (immutable.js:4403)
```

//Code of ProductsDashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loadProducts, removeProduct } from '../../actions/products_actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class ProductsDashboard extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.loadProducts();
  }

  removeProduct(product) {
    this.props.removeProduct(product);
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.products) {
      return <div>Producten worden geladen</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <a href="#/dashboard/products/add" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right" style={{marginBottom: '20px'}}>Product toevoegen</a>

        <div style={{marginBottom: '20px'}}>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Zoek product" />
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Barcode</td>
                <td>Naam</td>
                <td>Omschrijving</td>
                <td>Prijs</td>
                <td>Volume</td>
                <td>Eenheid</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              { this.props.products.map(function(product, index) {
                  var editUrl = `#/dashboard/products/edit/${product.get('id')}`;
                  return(
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td>{product.get('id')}</td>
                      <td>{product.get('barcode')}</td>
                      <td>{product.get('name')}</td>
                      <td>{product.get('description')}</td>
                      <td>{product.get('price')}</td>
                      <td>{product.get('volume')}</td>
                      <td>{product.get('unit')}</td>
                      <td><a href={editUrl} class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Wijzigen</a></td>
                      <td><button onClick={ this.removeProduct.bind(null, product) } class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Verwijderen</button></td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                })
              }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToPorps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ loadProducts, removeProduct }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    products: state.products.get('products')
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToPorps)(ProductsDashboard);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside the callback of `Array.prototype.map` is `undefined` unless specified otherwise:

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to map, it will used as callback's
>   this value. Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be used as its this
>   value. The this value ultimately observable by `callback` is determined
>   according to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a
>   function.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

---

To resolve this, pass a value for `thisArg`:

```
{ this.props.products.map(function(product, index) {
    var editUrl = `#/dashboard/products/edit/${product.get('id')}`;
        return(
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{product.get('id')}</td>
                <td>{product.get('barcode')}</td>
                <td>{product.get('name')}</td>
                <td>{product.get('description')}</td>
                <td>{product.get('price')}</td>
                <td>{product.get('volume')}</td>
                <td>{product.get('unit')}</td>
                <td><a href={editUrl} class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Wijzigen</a></td>
            <td><button onClick={ this.removeProduct.bind(null, product) } class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Verwijderen</button></td>
        </tr>
    )
}, this)}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well! But now I'm getting another error: Uncaught Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of null
    at removeProduct

Comment: That's because you bind `this` to `null`: `this.removeProduct.bind(null, product)`. As a result, accessing `this.props` inside `removeProduct` fails. instead, keep the binding intact and pass `product` by wrapping it: `onClick={() => this.removeProduct(product)}`